# Getting Devise to recognize my authentication module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am attempting to write my own Devise authentication module following the procedure outlined in http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/

I've created a User class under app/models and Devise::Models and Devise::Strategies modules under lib. I've also added:

```
require 'remote_authenticatable'  

config.warden do |manager|
   manager.strategies.add(:remote, Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable)
   manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :remote
end
```

to my initializers/devise.rb file.

And I've added:

```
devise_for :users
```

to my routes.rb

However, for some reason the sign_on and sign_off routes do not appear in my rake routes.

Is there some good documentation on how the Devise plugin works with these kinds of extensions?

Peter.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out.

I needed to add

```
Devise.add_module :remote_authenticatable, :controller => :sessions,  :route => { :session => :routes }
```

to my config/initializers/devise file. Can anyone explain what this line does? With particular focus on the last two parameters?

Comment: say i want to customize the session pages. so i override the devise controllers using "rails g devise:controllers users -c=sessions". Using the above settings, the new session controller is not accessible, nor is the new sign_in page rendered. How do we point it to the new page? I tried modifying the above to "config.add_module :remote_authenticatable, controller: 'users/sessions', route: { session: :routes }" but it doesnt work.

Answer (score -1):

it is called by default `sign_in` and `sign_out` :)